# Duplicate a chart object using xlsxwriter

Tags: python, python-3.x, charts, scatter-plot, xlsxwriter

I have one complicated scatter chart and I want to insert it in two different sheets of same workbook. But, when I tried to insert the same chart object into same or different sheet, it did not worked. Why is that so?
Is it possible to, may be, duplicate the original chart object, so that I can insert it in multiple sheets?

As a workaround, I understand that I need to create new chart every time and insert it. But, I want to understand why inserting same chart into different sheets doesn't work.

Below is reproduced code:

```
import xlsxwriter

a = [[222.724, 23.2381],
     [219.798, 27.2969], ]

wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('trial.xlsx')
sheetName = 'sheet1'
ws = wb.add_worksheet(sheetName)

ws.write_column(1, 0, ['A1', 'A2'])
ws.write_row(1, 1, a[0])
ws.write_row(2, 1, a[1])

chart = wb.add_chart({'type': 'scatter'})
chart.add_series({'name': 'Goodman', 'categories': [sheetName, 1, 1, 2, 1],
                  'values': [sheetName, 1, 2, 2, 2], })

ws.insert_chart(3, 4, chart)
ws.insert_chart(3, 14, chart)

ws2 = wb.add_worksheet('sheet2')
ws2.insert_chart(3, 4, chart)

wb.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer.

> Each chart object in the workbook needs to be created via add_chart(). 
> So, we need to create a new chart object each time.

[Link](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/184)

We can wrap this into a function, so that we can use it as many times as we want.
Full code below:

```
import xlsxwriter

a = [[222.724, 23.2381],
     [219.798, 27.2969]]

wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('trial.xlsx')

# Create the first worksheet and insert the chart
ws1 = wb.add_worksheet('sheet1')
ws1.write_column(1, 0, ['A1', 'A2'])
ws1.write_row(1, 1, a[0])
ws1.write_row(2, 1, a[1])

def create_chart_object():
    chart = wb.add_chart({'type': 'scatter'})
    chart.add_series({'name': 'Goodman', 'categories': ['sheet1', 1, 1, 2, 1],
                      'values': ['sheet1', 1, 2, 2, 2]})
    return chart

chart1 = create_chart_object()
chart2 = create_chart_object()
ws1.insert_chart(3, 4, chart1)

# Create the second worksheet and insert chart2
ws2 = wb.add_worksheet('sheet2')
ws2.insert_chart(3, 4, chart2)

wb.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason you are experiencing issues when inserting the same chart object into multiple sheets is because the chart object can only be associated with a single worksheet at a time in XlsxWriter.

When you insert the chart into a worksheet using the insert_chart method, it binds the chart object to that specific worksheet. If you try to insert the same chart object into another sheet, it won't work because the chart is already associated with the first sheet.

To insert the same chart into multiple sheets, you need to create separate chart objects for each worksheet. You can achieve this by duplicating the original chart object using the copy() method.

```
import xlsxwriter

a = [[222.724, 23.2381],
     [219.798, 27.2969]]

wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('trial.xlsx')

# Create the first worksheet and insert the chart
ws1 = wb.add_worksheet('sheet1')
ws1.write_column(1, 0, ['A1', 'A2'])
ws1.write_row(1, 1, a[0])
ws1.write_row(2, 1, a[1])

chart = wb.add_chart({'type': 'scatter'})
chart.add_series({'name': 'Goodman', 'categories': ['sheet1', 1, 1, 2, 1],
                  'values': ['sheet1', 1, 2, 2, 2]})

ws1.insert_chart(3, 4, chart)

# Create the second worksheet and insert a copy of the chart
ws2 = wb.add_worksheet('sheet2')
chart_copy = chart.copy()
ws2.insert_chart(3, 4, chart_copy)

wb.close()
```

Comment: There is no `copy` method. So, it won't work, I have checked!

Comment: You could copy the chart object using python copy but that still wouldn't work. There is a bit more to it